# Adding items to a scrollview makes it scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I am dynamically adding items to a `ScrollView` and it makes it scroll to the bottom. I would like it to stay on top.

I have a `ScrollView`, a vertical `LinearLayout`, some stuff and then a `ListView` that gets resized to the height of all its items so it does not scroll.

When I load my data and add it to the layout it scrolls!

Answer (score 0):

when you add item , you should tell your scrollView to stay on the Top via the method : [`scrollTo(int x, int y);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) :

```
 for(int i = 0; i<items.size();i++) {
        //adding items
    }
    //go to top atfer adding item
    scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bad idea to have a ListView inside a ScrollView.

I have solved similar problems by using a vertical LinearLayout that I add my rows into instead of a ScrollView. Since you are always displaying all items in the list, this solution should work fine.